# Plotly string versus date

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I am having an issue with a Plotly scatter graph. The X axis is a date in the format YYYY-WW. WW stands for week number. If I convert that to date time format, Plotly is unable to interpret it, since it is expecting a month. If I leave it as a string, then Plotly complains "ValueError: Could not convert value of 'x' ('x') into a numeric type. If 'x' contains stringified dates, please convert to a datetime column.".

I just want Plotly to use X axis as a category for the scatter graph. Not a date, and don't try to convert into numeric type.

```
year_week = [ '2020-00', '2020-01', '2020-02', '2020-03' ]
num_accidents = [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

fig_ = px.scatter(
                     x=year_week,
                     y=num_accidents,
                     trendline='ols',
                     title="Number of Accidents Per Week")

    fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
    fig.update_layout(xaxis_type='category')
    fig.update_traces(mode='lines')
```

Comment: Pls provide the code and input data (at least a sample in text format) so that we can understand the issue. It is generally recommended that date be input as datetime format, not text/categorical data. You can set the format and frequency of the tick labels if you don't like it

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the date format to datetime using `strptime()`, which will change it to the right datetime format. Note that `%W` is for the week-of-year number and it needs to be accompanied by `%w`, which is the day of the week. The week should start from `01`, not `00` as there is not week-0 as far as datetime is concerned. I have made that change. Note that I have added `-1` as this will take the first day of the week. The code is shown below. Once created, the date times should show up correctly. I have done an `update_xaxes()` to demonstrate how to change the axis format, in case you don't like the default as well.

```
year_week = [ '2020-01', '2020-02', '2020-03', '2020-04' ]
num_accidents = [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

import datetime
year_week = [datetime.datetime.strptime(date + '-1',"%Y-%W-%w") for date in year_week]

fig = px.scatter(
                     x=year_week,
                     y=num_accidents,
                     trendline='ols',
                     title="Number of Accidents Per Week")

#fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
#fig.update_layout(xaxis_type='category')
fig.update_traces(mode='lines')
fig.update_xaxes(tickformat="%d-%b-%Y")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is super helpful. I was wondering though, can't I force Plotly to not interpret the X axis automatically? Right now Plotly is saying 'this looks like a date, I will try to apply date rules to it.'I want my X axis data to be just 'categories' or 'buckets'. The reason I am asking is that I am not getting an error "ValueError: time data '2019-01  -1' does not match format '%Y-%W-%w'"

Comment: Err, typo in the previous comment not should be now.

Comment: I am not sure how to add a screenshot to this, so I created another question as a followup. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73856626/plotly-scatter-trendline-is-straight