# Plotly Scatter Trendline is straight?

Tags: plot, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am trying to get Plotly to draw a trendline, using scatter graph, and for some odd reason the line is straight, which makes no sense. The Y axis values are numbers between the range of 0 to 10, but when I hover over the trendline the numbers appears as exponentials, which makes no sense.

```
mylist = [datetime.datetime.strptime(date + '-1', "%Y-%W-%w") for date in mylist]

    fig = px.scatter(
                     x=mylist,
                     y=num_accidents,
                     trendline='ols',
                     title="Number of Accidents Per Week")

    fig.update_traces(mode='lines')
    fig.update_xaxes(tickformat="%d-%b-%Y")
```

[image: Trendline]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sorting your x axis as in:

```
mylist = [datetime.datetime.strptime(date + '-1', "%Y-%W-%w") for date in mylist]

mylist = sorted(mylist)

fig = px.scatter(
                 x=mylist,
                 y=num_accidents,
                 trendline='ols',
                 title="Number of Accidents Per Week")

fig.update_traces(mode='lines')
fig.update_xaxes(tickformat="%d-%b-%Y")
```